# create dynamic class in ES6

Tags: javascript, oop, object, inheritance, ecmascript-6

is that possible to extends the class without writing the current class name? 
example, I have class `Animal`

like this

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(foot, livein) {
    this.foot = foot;
    this.livein = livein;
  }
}
```

I want to extends that class Animal with many kinds of Animals, I am sure I should create a lot of Animals name classes,

like `class Bear extends Animal (){},`

```
class Cat extends Animal (){},
class Pig extends Animal(){}
```

and how about if we have 100 kinds of animals ? should we write one by one for that name? 
and is that possible if we don't do that?

I want to shorthand them like this without creat many kinds of classes,

```
let pig = new Pig(4, 'woods') // Pig {foot: 4, livein: 'woods'}
let cat = new Cat(4, 'around us') // Cat {foot: 4, livein: 'around us'}
```

*that pig and cat output because extends from Animal class*

is that possible to write many kinds of extends from Animal without creating them but create them on a variable ??

I hope my question makes sense :D

Comment: Why not `class extends Animal`?

Comment: i just want to create name of animals to extends with the Animal classes, but i dont to know is that possible to create names of classes to extends with Animal with variable, and without write them in to in `class` and `super` @dotconnor